# Sending multipart request by aiohttp

Tags: multipart, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

I trying to make test case for my view, and now I would to send mutipart request with user credentials containing user image. I use MultipartWriter but, when I'm trying to read parts, I get part as None. I'm sure that my test case is wrong written.
Thanks for your help, and sorry for my bad english.

My test case:

```
async def test_users_post(app):
    with open('user_photo.jpg', 'rb') as file:
        user_data = dict(
            name='Test1',
            password='Password',
            grand=True,
            description='Blank',
            email='test@test.ru',
            file=file
        )
        with MultipartWriter() as mpwriter:
            mpwriter.append_form([(key, value) for key, value in user_data.items()])
            response = await app['client'].post('/users', data=mpwriter)
            assert response.status == 201
```

Start lines of view:

```
    async def post(self):
    reader = await self.request.multipart()

    async with self.request.app['db'].acquire() as conn:
        data = {}
        while True:
            field = await reader.next()
            print(field) # field is None here
            if not field:
                # If not fields were read
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay I had found way, which doesn't need multipart writer.
Now I user aiohttp.FormData for packing user credentials.

```
async def test_users_post(app):
    form = aiohttp.FormData()
    user_data = dict(
        name='Test1',
        password='Password',
        description='Blank',
        email='test@test.ru',
    )
    for key, value in user_data.items():
        form.add_field(key, value)
    form.add_field('photo', open('user_photo.jpg', 'rb'))
    response = await app['client'].post('/users', data=form)
    assert response.status == 201
```